# visual studio 2015 nuget solution is not saved how to fix it?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, nuget

When using Nuget I see this error:

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Do not be lazy, post the error message as text: “Solution is not saved. Please save your solution before managing NuGet packages.” — googling for this may lead you to [GitHub topic](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1815) where it is explained that you need an open and non-modified solution at all times: the “No solution” scenario is not supported.

Comment: try ctrl + shift + s  and saved soluion

Comment: Had this same issue with vs 2017. Have an upvote

Comment: The same issue with VS Community 2015 on every project / solution, even the one that worked on the past

Answer (score 27):

Just as answered by Jack, or you can close the VS directly and there will be a dialog box that let you save the .sln file, after which you can solve it.

Answer (score 14):

I could repro this issue if I open the project file directly without the solution file(.sln).

So just click the save button in your VS IDE, it will let you save the .sln file, and then re-install your package again.

[image]

Comment: Problem is that sometimes people work with temporary projects that don't need saving (and polluting any source controlled file structure), but are annoyed and/or confused by this error.

Answer (score 7):

in Visual studio --> goto file --> save All 
it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just build your application and the error will automatically removed. This is due to your solution was modified when merging code, etc.